# Data VS Async Data in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im using `vue.js` with `nuxt.js`, I'm just still confused as when to use Data VS Async Data. Why would I need to use Async data when I just have data that just displays on the page?

I have a data object of FAQ's and just want to display the data without doing anything with it. What are the benefits of using the asyncData? Or what are the cases or best use of them?

Should I display list data such as this as async by default if using data such as this inside of my component?

**Data**

```
 data:() => ({
   faqs:[
     {"title":"faq1"},
     {"title":"faq2"},
     {"title":"faq3"},
    ]
 }),
```

**asyncData**

```
asyncData(context) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({
                colocationFaqs:[
                    {"title":"faq1"},
                    {"title":"faq2"},
                    {"title":"faq3"},
                ]
            });
        })
        .then(data => {
            return data
        })
        .catch(e => {
            context.error(e);
        });
    },
```

Comment: you use nuxt.js right?

Comment: Yes i'm using nuxt

Comment: Its already explained in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/)

Comment: Iv'e read the docs and as I've said in my question, i'm still confused, why would I need to pre render it when it is going to be displayed anyway

Answer (score 2):

`asyncData` happes on the serer-side. You cant access browser things like `localStorage` or `fetch()` for example but on the ther hand you can access server-side things.

So why should you use `asyncData` instead of vue cycles like `created`?

The benefit to use `asyncData` is SEO and speed. There is this special `context` argument. It contains things like your `store` with `context.store`. Its special because `asyncData` happens on server-side but the store is on the client side usually. That means you can get some data and then populate your store with it and somewhere else you display it. The benefit of this is that its all server-side and that increase your SEO so for example the google crawler doesnt see a blank page

> why would I need to pre render it when it is going to be displayed
>   anyway

Yes for us it doesnt matter if i send 1 File to the client and it renders all data like in SPA's or if its pre-rendered. But it doesnt matter for the google crawler. If you use SPA mode the crawler just sees a blank page. You can discoverd it too. Go to any SPA website and click right-click and inspect you will see thats there only 1 Div tag and few `<script>` tags. (Dont press F12 and inspect like this thats not what i mean).

Comment: I'm using universal mode with pre-rendered html files

Comment: @ottz0 did you understand it or still confused?

Comment: Thanks, yes understand, it's kind of what I thought.....Would you use fetch if you stored the data in the store rather than in the component? Or should you use asyncData to access context.store as you've said

Comment: if i want SEO benefits i use `asyncData` and populate the store, then in my component i get the data for example like this `computed: { posts: this.$store.state.posts }`. `asyncData` similar to created, if you visit some page the `asyncData` is the first function that is gonna executed

Comment: Ok thanks for that...So you add the data to the store on the server first with async, then once the page has loaded just get it from the store? I use mapGetters for this

Comment: @ottz0 yea, then you should see the data if you make a rightclick and click on inspect. Thats a easy way to check if its server side rendered or not.

Comment: Yes If I right click now it's not HTML and the element is "quoted with data" and the data is now inside of window.__NUXT__=function....So this tells me it has been rendered on the server rather than on the browser? If now it's rendered on the server

Comment: @ottz0 `asyncData` is used if you visit a page and you want it to get first pre-rendered. There is a another function called `nuxtServerInit()` its the same with 1 difference. It gets executed whenever you refresh the page or enter the page for the first time, `asyncData` works for pages where you put it

Comment: One more thing is that I'm using universal mode and i'm pre-rendering the files anyway into HTML files which are now flat and you don't need a server to process anything, so Google will now see these files on load anyway even if I don't use asyncData?

Comment: @ottz0 ofcorse hard coded things will get pre-rendered. But imagine things like Blog posts. You need to fetch them first from the database and display it on the page. With `asyncData` or `nuxtServerInit` you are able pre-render this dynamic data so google crawlers sees the content.

Comment: @ottz0 with rightclick inspect i mean the sourcecode

Comment: Great thanks, that's clearer..Just getting back to my original question then is I don't need to do anything with my faq's data anyway but display it. And because i'm in universal mode with pre rendered html files, nuxt creates two copies of the data, one on the server and one on the client which is why there's two entries of my text. I wouldn't need to use asyncData in this case. (Again as per your response only for dynamic data that need to be passed and pre rendered or in a SPA only app)

Comment: @ottz0 yea thats hardcoded so you dont need it. use it for things like blogposts, an shop, things like that thats dynamic